How to quickly determine if A - (A ∩ (ΣBi)) set exists and pick a random value from it?
I am trying to make my python code randomly and quickly find a point (x,y) in the A disc and that is not part of any other present discs, if that point does exist. However, the only method I have found is a long and labourous method since it randomly picks a point and checks if it corresponds to or not. However, in the event where over 99% of the A disc is intersecting with other Bi discs, it evidently is near impossible.
I can't seem to find a better solution. By hand it's simple, but in the discreet domain of algorithms it's harder.
Would any of you have an idea?
Attached is an illustration of the problem, where the blue section represents the area in which the point can be randomly selected.
Thanks in advance for your help.
Doualamm
example of problem set

when you say "randomly find a point", do you mean that it should be sampling a uniform distribution over the uncovered part of $A$, or you just want some point that is there?

By randomly I mean selecting any point in the uncovered part of A.

And how many disks $B_j$ do you typically have?

I can have from 50 to over 5000. However, I do not know how many disks overlap the A disk.
